# CloudZoom Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I found a few people have also encountered the same problem, I have followed their solutions but they are still not working for me....

I have followed the guide from the following website:
[Plugin Guide](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/quickstart)

Also included the required script:

```
<script src="js/cloud-zoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I have then called the quick start function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        CloudZoom.quickStart();
</script>
```

But I got the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CloudZoom is not defined.

Is there any possibility of causing this problem or any other way that I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: where have you included the reference to script for CloudZoom in your HTML page ?

Comment: @Agalo yes, I have included the script as listed from the guide.

Comment: can you show that code ?

Comment: ＠Agalo I have edited my question, thanks

Comment: first you've to download the cloudzoom.js and then create a new directory named 'js' on the same directory as the html page and place the cloudzoom.js file on that directory. Example: if your html page is in 'E:\Test Project\' then create a new directory/folder name 'js' as 'E:\Test Project\js' and place the cloudzoom.js in that folder, so the location of that js file will be 'E:\Test Project\js\cloudzoom.js'

Comment: ＠Aminur Rashid I have made changes on the file name as you suggested but I still got the same error

Comment: also, did you add jquery?

Comment: Yes I have added...
`<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: did the js folder has 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js' file in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133712/discussion-between-aminur-rashid-and-sammi).